# How to speed up this Apache log parsing?

Tags: python, apache, parsing, logging, shlex

I'm parsing big Apache logs like:

```
example.com:80 1.2.3.4 - - [01/Jul/2021:06:12:12 +0000] "GET /test/example/index.php?a=b&c=d HTTP/1.1" 302 486 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36"
```

with:

```
import apache_log_parser, shlex
parser = apache_log_parser.make_parser("%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"")
with open("access.log") as f:
    for l in enumerate(f):
        x = parser(l)
```

- For each line, it takes ~0.1 ms (i5 laptop) / ~0.9ms (low-end Atom CPU N2800 1.86GHz)
  This is quite slow: nearly one millisecond for each line!
- So I decided to do my  own parsing with `shlex` (which deals nicely with quotes such as`first "second block" "third block" fourth`).
  It's worse! I get, per line, ~0.3 ms (i5 laptop) / ~1.6ms low-end server

  ```
  with open("access.log") as f:
      for l in enumerate(f):
          x = shlex.split(l)
  ```
- Question: **Which faster method (maybe with direct regex?) could allow the parsing of such logs?** I only need `server port ip datetime url status bytes referer useragent`.

Comment: How many milliseconds per line would you consider to be  "fast enough"? Have you tried profiling to see what is the "slow" part?

Comment: Do those ms numbers include reading the line (i.e. I/O) or those are just for the parser?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye For the parsing, the I/O is negligible here (if I remove the parsing and replace by `l.lower()` for example, it's several orders of magnitude faster)

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes, the bottleneck is `shlex.split(l)` or `parser(l)`; the IO is negligible. `0.1 ms` per line is the goal I'd like to attain on the low-end server. Other tools (such as `goaccess`) achieve this on the same server, so it's possible to reach this, i.e. a 10x improvement

Comment: `goaccess` is implemented in C so don't expect any Python solution to be as fast

Comment: @DeepSpace In my Python (and Cython and Numpy) experience, you are *rarely* stuck with a performance issue in Python; either you call the right library or you can recode something in Cython, ... finally you always get *not so far* from the C speed ;)

Comment: Numpy *is* implemented in C...

Comment: @DeepSpace That's *exactly* what I meant :) Often you end up calling libraries that are coded in compiled languages such as C. So you finally get close to C speed, with Python you're just plugging pipes together, I'm sure we can agree with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution that does a x10 speed improvement: pure regex.

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'(?P<server>.*?):(?P<port>.*?) (?P<ip>.*?) (?P<remote_log_name>.*?) (?P<userid>.*?) \[(?P<date>.*?)\] \"(?P<request>.*?)\" (?P<status>.*?) (?P<length>.*?) \"(?P<referer>.*?)\" \"(?P<useragent>.*?)\"')

with open("access.log") as f:
    for l in enumerate(f):
        d = next(r.finditer(l)).groupdict()
        d['url'] = d['request'].split()[1] if ' ' in d['request'] else '-'
        # d['date'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(d['date'], '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z').isoformat()  # optional
```

~ 0.01 ms per line on my i5 laptop.